# Client certificate with IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I have a client who wants to secure the connection to his application with a client certificate. He doesn't want to map the certificate to a login.

He doesn't want to buy a certificate from trusted CA and wants me to provide him my own self-signed certificate.

I followed the steps from this article :
http://asoftwaredeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/x-509-certificate/
(every time I search on Google I end on this)

I managed to generate the two certificates and to set them both up in the client and server.

However, I still get the same 403.7 error.

Does anybody have a real step by step guide with ALL the steps?
Am I the only one who wants to do such a simple thing?
Why isn't it clearly described in the documentation?

Comment: Have you added your generated certificate to the Trusted Root Certificate store of the computer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step by step:

1. Generate your CA
2. Generate your client certs and add sign them with the CA
3. Open MMC (Windows 7 just type MMC in the dialog)
4. Click file>add/remove snap-in...
5. Click certificates then add
6. When prompted select computer account
7. When prompted again select local computer
8. Double click on certificates
9. Click on Trusted Root Certification Authorities
10. Click on certificates
11. Click on more actions > import
12. Find and select your Root CA Certificate
    13  Open Internet Information Services Manager
13. Click on your server
14. Click on Server Certificates
15. Import your CA certificate
16. Click on your site
17. Click on bindings
18. Add a new one for https
19. Make sure to select your CA certificate
20. Click ok.
21. Return to your site menu
22. Click on SSL Settings
23. Check require SSL
24. Click on require in the radio buttons
25. Return to site's menu
26. Click on authentication
27. Enable anonymous authentication (it will still ask for a certificate)
28. Restart IIS (all of it, not just the site)
29. Install the client certificate into the browser
30. Go to the site with https:// and not http://
31. Browser should prompt depending on settings

    - Every client must trust the CA so you will have to convince every user to install your CA cert to their computer.